# Run failed: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge - main

Tags: reactjs, git, firebase, github, firebase-authentication

I'm using React, Firebase, and Vite for my TodoMate project and having issues with deploying it.

Every time I run git push to push on github, I receive an email stating the error msg mentioned in title. I tried deploying it on Netlify, but for some reason, after logging in, the routes are constantly switching between "/login" and "/overview".

Firebase hosted link: https://todomate-f955d.web.app
Netlify Link: https://app-todomate.netlify.app

My code is working fine on localhost but idk why it is behaving this way on production.
Can anyone tell me if there's any problem with my code?

// Current Layout.tsx

```
const Layout = () => {
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  const location = useLocation();

  if (location.pathname === "/")
    return user ? <Navigate to="/overview" /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;

  return (
    <Stack direction="row">
      <Box sx={{ display: { xs: "none", sm: "block", height: "100vh" } }}>
        <Sidebar />
      </Box>
      <Home />
    </Stack>
  );
};
```

// PrivateRoutes.tsx

```
const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = () => {
      auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
          setUser(user);
          navigate("/overview");
        } else {
          navigate("/login");
        }
      });
    };

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return user ? <Layout /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
};
```

I tried attaching onAuthStateChanged on Layout.tsx, and this was working fine on localhost as it redirected logged-in users to the overview page. Should i use this Layout.tsx or the above one is okay?

```
const Layout = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = () => {
      auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
          setUser(user);
          navigate("/overview");
        } else {
          navigate("/login");
        }
      });
    };

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  if (location.pathname === "/")
    return user ? <Navigate to="/overview" /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;

  return (
    <Stack direction="row">
      <Box sx={{ display: { xs: "none", sm: "block", height: "100vh" } }}>
        <Sidebar />
      </Box>
      <Home />
    </Stack>
  );
};
```

edit:
I push my code on github.
It has two action workflows made by firebase cli

1. deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge

```
# firebase-hosting-merge.yml
# This file was auto-generated by the Firebase CLI
# https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_TODOMATE_F955D }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: todomate-f955d
```

2. deploy to Firebase Hosting on PR

```
# firebase-hosting-pull-request.yml
# This file was auto-generated by the Firebase CLI
# https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on PR
'on': pull_request
jobs:
  build_and_preview:
    if: '${{ github.event.pull_request.head.repo.full_name == github.repository }}'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: npm ci && npm run build
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_TODOMATE_F955D }}'
          projectId: todomate-f955d
```

Comment: Your post talks about "git push" but you don't state where you are pushing to, nor how the system you are pushing to is set up.  Is this pushing to GitHub and your project has a GitHub Action configured to build and deploy?  If not, how else have you been deploying?  Also, you say you try to deploy it to netlify but then you share a Firebase project URL.  This is all quite confusing to me.

Comment: @GregFenton I've updated the question and added what you asked for. Please see if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues worthy of attention.

First, this code:

```js
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  const location = useLocation();

  if (location.pathname === "/")
    return user ? <Navigate to="/overview" /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
```

is problematic because `auth.currentUser` (assuming that `auth` is a handle to the Auth service) is a value that gets set ***asynchronously***.  If your code runs `auth.currentUser` before the login process (which is asynchronous!) completes, then the value will be null or undefined.  I personally never use the value `auth.currentUser`.  Instead, Firebase provides the `onAuthStateChanged()` listener that gets notified when the login process has completed.

Typically you want to call `onAuthStateChanged()` at the beginning of your app so that the listener is running and waiting for Auth events (user completed logging in or logging out).  Then you typically capture the value from that listener, save it to a state variable, and then use that state variable throughout the rest of your code (instead of `auth.currentUser` which you have no idea if when it gets set or unset).

[Here is a React/Vite/Firebase "starter app"](https://github.com/gregfenton/react-and-user-profiles-with-firebase-auth-and-firestore) with a provider named `AuthProvider.jsx` that shows one way to capture the authentication events and make them available to the rest of the application.  It also maintains  "realtime" user profile data.

Second, the way that you are invoking `onAuthStateChanged()` in the PrivateRoutes is problematic in that the auth listener is being started late into your app startup (or even after that).  Again, reflect on the way that `AuthProvider.jsx` is coded and called in the above starter app.